# Using ImageCopyResampled possibly causing memory shortages on files > 1MB

Tags: php, gd

I have an app which I allow users to upload photos to. First I save the image to the server and then I use ImageCopyResampled() and it's friends to resize the image, then replace the old larger image with this new version.

It all works ok on smaller images (size wise, dimensions don't seem to matter) but on larger images the function appears to be breaking at the point I call the ImageCopyResampled function.

On my localhost the largest sized image file the script will process ok is 2MB. On the live server it's only 1MB.

After some checking and reading on here I found out about php.ini's settings for memory limits, on my localhost:

```
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

and yet it still won't let me sample an image bigger than 2MB

On my live server (which works up to 1MB) I've asked my host who've said that my package only has a 30 MB of memory limit. Surely a 1MB file which is manipulated by ImageCopyResampled() wouldn't take up 30MB of memory.

Can anyone tell me if it is in fact ImageCopyResampled() and the lack of memory that's causing the problem? If so, is there anything I can do about it? If not, is there anything obvious that might be the problem?

Comment: The file size is not really relevant for compressed formats like JPG; it's the file's dimensions that are, because the file needs to be "unpacked" in memory before it can be resized. A 1000 x 1000 Pixel image will need at the very least 1000 x 1000 x 3 bytes (one byte each for Red, Green, and Blue) - more likely double that during a resize operation. Either way, you should be getting an error message showing you exactly at which point the problem occurs. Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: As images typically take up 3bytes per pixel (R G and B) when being manipulated by gd, they can easily eat large amounts of memory

Comment: But if I try an image which is 8000x8000 and only 1MB it works. But a file 4000x4000 and 2MB doesn't. So I guess it's not a memory problem then anyway?

Comment: In that case it shouldn't be - strange. (Maybe it's the image's format that's the problem then.) Either way, do some debugging on the script, activate error reporting, etc. to see what's going on. All we here can do is guess.